# Spring MVC with AJAX / JSON - Loading a new page - how can I access the URL data?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC in the backend system and HTML, AJAX, JSON with jQuery in the frontend system.
I have two pages. The first one is called:
http://localhost:8080/myproject/start

There I initialize data and make AJAX/JSON calls within jQuery's

```
$(document).ready(function() { ... });
```

But in this page I have a link on the next page:
http://localhost:8080/myproject/nextpage/ID
where ID is an unique number.

The problem is, this number do I need in the backend system to load more data.
So I have in the backend system:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/nextpage/{ID}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String getCreateForm(Model model) {
    return "nextpage/nameofthejsp";
}
```

So all I do is to call the JSP and there is also a

```
    $(document).ready(function() { ... });
```

So, how can I access the ID number of the URL within jQuery?
Or, I have this ID number first in the backend system, can I handle this number there instead of loading the frontend and then make a call to the backend?

Does anyone has an idea?

Best Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure i understand correctly; You want to access the ID in the next page?

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
@RequestMapping(value="/nextpage/{ID}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String getCreateForm(@PathVariable("ID") int id, Model model) {
/** 
Do something
**/
    model.addAttribute("ID", id);
    return "nextpage/nameofthejsp";
}
```

and in your nextpage/nameofthejsp JSP, ID will be accessible:  ${ID}

Comment: Oh yes, tis is what I am searching for. But how can I access it in the frontend system. Perhaps you can tell me how to put this into a JavaScript alert(); message?

Comment: @Tim It would be: 
    alert('your id is ${id}');
jstl has been used to print the id value. You can find more info about jstl in http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jstl0211.html